# Replacing file path in excel with another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel file with cells that retrieve data from a file stored on another computer. I need to update the file path in all of these formulas but it is extremely tedious as each time I update the formula, an open file window comes up. The location that I am changing this to is also not on my computer.

Is there a quick way to update a file path formula without having this dialog window open up?

I need to change my path from

`='\\clusfs001nas\`

To:

`='R:\`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the "Data" Tab, click "Edit Links" - this should show you the files you have linked to, and you can "Change Source" to update it.  Alternatively, you could do a simple Find/Replace (CTRL+F, then click "replace" and type the path you need to replace and then in the replace area, put the new path).

Comment: I am using the replace functionality but unfortunately it opens a dialog box each time i click replace. Was trying to see if there was a more efficient way of doing this directly in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you try doing Edit Links? Did that work?  Another idea is, if you have the same formula going down an entire column - why not either delete all cells, except the first, or just paste the values on all but first row, fix that formula, then re-run the formula down the column?

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, I cannot update the source since the file for the new path is not on this computer and yes what I have been ultimately doing is changing the path on the first row of the column and dragging it down :)

Comment: You should still be able to direct it to a network folder.  I have some Excel workbooks with a few links to network drives, and it works without issue.

Comment: unfortunately it seems to require a file, not just a network folder.

Comment: I thought you were trying to use a file?  "I have an excel file with cells that retrieve data from a file stored on another computer" - can you not access the file from your computer? If you can't, then no solution (VBA, etc.) would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can change formulas using VBA.

But first, I suggest you have it in **only one cell**, and in the formulas, you add this cell, not a real path. This way, next time you need to change it, you change only one cell.

Now the coding, an example to change A2 and B5:

```
Sub Change()
    Range("A2").Formula = type the formula here between quotes
    Range("B5").Formula = type the formula here between quotes
end sub
```

If you have lots of cells in a column, you could do a loop:

```
For i = 1 to 20 'say you have cells from row 1 to 20
    Cells(i,3).Formula = type the formula here between quotes
    'the number 3 above is the third column: C
next
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that I would not have to revert to VBA for this but I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but one option that can avoid the annoying dialog when you click Replace All is to insert some random characters at the beginning of the path which will prevent Excel from thinking that the string is an actual link.  Then you should be able to edit the portions of that path that need to be changed, and once that is complete, do another Replace ALL, basically removing the random characters that were inserted.

You need to be careful of course, because if you choose a random character that happens to be within other formulas the Replace ALL may have some unexpected results

Answer (score -1):

You can write on your code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdate = False
```